# Waiting Dialog doesn't works correctly and the app freezes until the task end

Tags: android, android-asynctask, busy-waiting

I have a class that sends various mail with attachments.

Because the method `sendEmail(addresses);` requires time to upload the attachments and send the emails, I have created an AsyncTask to show a waiting dialog,

however, unfortunately, during the sending the app freezes until it has terminated the sending without showing anything (or sometimes shows a frozen waiting windows for a little instant before the end of procedure)

The related parts of code in my class are the follows

```
public class MyClass extends Activity {
    ...

    private ProgressDialog waitingDialog;

    ....

    OnClickListener mInvia = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
                new MyAsyncTaskClass().execute(new String[] {});
        }
    };

    public void prepareSending() {
        String x = "";
        for (String s : selectedMails) {
            x += (s + ";");
        }
        String[] addresses = x.split(";");
        sendEmail(addresses);
    }

    private void openFile() {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        i.setType("file/*");
        startActivityForResult(i, FILE_REQ_CODE);
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
            Intent intentData) {

        Uri tmp = intentData.getData();
        filePath=getRealPath(tmp);
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intentData);

    }


    public void sendEmail(String[] addresses) {

        Mail m = new Mail("sendermail@sample.com",
                "senderpassword");

        name = editor1.getText().toString();
        subject = editor2.getText().toString();
        text = editor3.getText().toString();
        emailReply = editor4.getText().toString();

        m.setTo(addresses);
        m.setFrom(emailReply);
        m.setSubject(subject);
        m.setBody(text + "\n\n\n Sent by" + name);
        try {
            m.send();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("MyClass", "Cannot send email", e);
        }

        try {
            m.addAttachment(filePath);

            if (m.send()) {
                Alerts.Ok(MyClass.this);
                nSuccess++;
            } else {
                Alerts.ErrorSending(MyClass.this);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Alerts.ErrorAttachment(MyClass.this);
        }

    }

    //inner class that should show a waiting windows
    private class MyAsyncTaskClass extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            waitingDialog = new ProgressDialog(MyClass.this);
            waitingDialog.setMessage("Loading ....");
            waitingDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            waitingDialog.setCancelable(true);
            waitingDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(final String... strings) {
            try {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        prepareSending();
                    }

                });
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void params) {
            waitingDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    //end innerclass
    // start context menu code
    ......

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Problem

I'd wager it's because you're running everything on the UI thread:

```
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(final String... strings) {
        try {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    prepareSending();
                }

            });
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return null;
    }
```

#### Do this instead!

Run all your `doInBackground` code based on non-UI-reliant things.

```
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(final String... strings) {
        prepareSending();
        return null;
    }
```

#### Accessing the UI

If you need to access data from the UI, or anything else on the UI thread, do that *first*.

```
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // Find all your "editor" fields here, and save them to member variables within the AsyncTask.
        // ...
    }
```

#### Then send those to your method

In `prepareSending` and `sendEmail` accept that data as parameters:

```
public void prepareSending(String name, String subject, String text, String emailReply) {
    // ...
    sendEmail(addresses, name, subject, text, emailReply);
}
public void sendEmail(String[] addresses, String name, String subject, String text, String emailReply) {
    // ...
}
```

And lastly, you need to send those from `doInBackground`:

```
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(final String... strings) {
        prepareSending(mName, mSubject, mText, mEmailReply); // The local fields you saved earlier
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: I get the Error E/AndroidRuntime(10921): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Comment: You probably have some code in your `Mail` class which references the UI. (Like a `Toast` message.)

Comment: Alerts.Ok(MyClass.this); Alerts.ErrorSending(MyClass.this); shows dialog windows, are these the cause of the problem? How I could fix?

Comment: Those should be sent after the emails are finished (in `onPostExecute`), otherwise they'll be shown after every email is sent. But yes, those need to be run on the UI thread. (You could use the same method you did before, with the `runOnUiThread` method.)

Comment: In my old method the alerts was showed correctly... one for every invocation of Async, sendMail(..) receives an array of email address, Now I don't know how to show alerts related to the sendMail() success, attacchmentNotSAend, or no-success if nothing is sent for network problems

Answer (score 0):

This is not the recommended way of doing:

```
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(final String... strings) {
        try {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    prepareSending();
                }

            });
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return null;
    }
```

You should use publishProgress() in order to run stuff on the UI thread as your processing is going on.

That said, you are also not managing the cases where the activity can be destroyed. This could lead to memory leaks and multiple AsyncTasks running in the background.

Try to get to something like:

```
public static class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

  MyAsyncTask(MyActivity a) {
    activity = new WeakReference<MyActivity>(a);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute() {
    if (activity.get()!=null) activity.get().showDialog();
  }

  @Override
  protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    // Upload data from here
  }
  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Void params) {    
    if (activity.get()!=null) activity.get().dismissDialog();
  }


  private WeakReference<MyActivity> activity;
}
```

Your activity is respondible for saving the task as a non-instance state, closing and recreating the dialog when appropriate, ...

Finally, pass all the information needed to send the mail to your task constructor (content, subject, ...). All the UI accesses will then be done on the UI thread when you create the task (not in doInBackground as you do curently).

Comment: I have understand that there was a problem with my AsyncTask... however I haven't idea of how to fix it. Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Problems lies here:

```
try {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    prepareSending();
                }

            });
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

1) prepareSending(); method is called on the UI thread. Refer [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to understand how to use **AsyncTask** in **Android**

2) Also it seems like you have habit of catching generic exceptions and also not handling them. Refer [Code Style Guidelines](http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html#dont-catch-generic-exception). It will help you a lot.

Good Luck ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
private class MyAsyncTaskClass extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Integer> {
        ProgressDialog waitingDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            waitingDialog = new ProgressDialog(MyClass.this);
            waitingDialog.setMessage("Loading ....");
            waitingDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            waitingDialog.setCancelable(true);
        }

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(final String... strings) {
            setProgress(-1);
            // long process start
            prepareSending();
            // long process end
            setProgress(-2);
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {

            if (values[0] == -1) {
                waitingDialog.show();
            } else if (values[2] == -2) {
                waitingDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Integer onPostExecute(Integer params) {
        }
    }
```